# Name for this function invocation style

Tags: functional-programming

Functions can be written in a way to permit the "spreading" of invocations

```
console.assert(add(1,2,3,4) === 10, '1+2+3+4 should be 10');
console.assert(add(1,2)(3)(4)() === 10, '1+2+3+4 should be 10'); // "spread" invocation
```

What is the name for this pattern?

Comment: I think in JavaScript, but the question is language agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Imagine that `add` is a function that receives 4 arguments:

```
function add(a,b,c,d);
```

If you pass exactly 4 arguments, it returns the sum of all of them.

If you pass 3, (e.g. a=1, b=2, c=3) it will return a function that receives one parameter and adds that to 1+2+3 (the values of a,b,c).

If you pass 2, it will return a function that receives two parameters and returns the sum of those with the intial 2 parameters that you passed.

An example, if you, like me, have from a imperative language background.

```
function add(a, b, c, d){
    if(arguments.length < 1){
        return add
    } else if(arguments.length < 2){
        return function(b, c, d) { return add(a,b,c,d) }
    } else if(arguments.length < 3){
        return function(c, d) { return add(a,b,c,d) }
    } else if(arguments.length < 4){
        return function(d) { return add(a,b,c,d) }
    } else {
        return a+b+c+d; 
    }
}
```